# Modifying JSON Dictionaries by deleting Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, function, dictionary, format

I am trying to write a piece of code where it filters out the values `RSI, MOM, MOM_RSI` within the Json file and filters by `Status`. I want to get rid of the values that has a `Status` of `ACTIVE` and get rid of the one that have a status of `PAUSED`. How will I be able to do that?

Code:

```
def reading(): 
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return data
reading()
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "RSI": [
      {
        "TradingPair": "BTCUSD",
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
      }
    ],
    "MOM_RSI":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BTCUSDT",
            "Status": "ACTIVE",
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "RSI": [
      {
        "TradingPair": "BTCUSD",
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
      }
    ],
    "MOM":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BCHUSDT",
            "Status": "PAUSED",
        }
    ],
    "MOM_RSI":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BTCUSDT",
            "Status": "ACTIVE",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the data. You can use your function, too

```
>>> with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
```

Create a dictionary named result.

```py
>>> result = {}
```

Then, go over the keys of the data, go over each dictionary in that
filtered list, if the status is `'ACTIVE'`, then either append to `result[filter_key]` if the key already exists in `result`, or create a key for this filter key.

```
>>> for filter_key in data.keys():
        for d in data[filter_key]:
            if d['Status'] == 'ACTIVE':
                try:
                    result[filter_key].append(d)
                except KeyError:
                    result[filter_key] = [d]
>>> result
{'RSI': [{'TradingPair': 'BTCUSD', 'Status': 'ACTIVE'}],
 'MOM_RSI': [{'TradingPair': 'BTCUSDT', 'Status': 'ACTIVE'}]}
```

Comment: Is there a way I could make the `['RSI', 'MOM', 'MOM_RSI']` modular so that it gets auto adjusted to the length instead of stating the list as is.

Comment: Sure. Edited my post.