# Filtering a json dictionary by values Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop, filter

I am trying to write a piece of code where it filters out the values `RSI, MOM, MOM_RSI` within the Json file and filters by `Status`. I want to keep the values that has a Status of ACTIVE and get rid of the one that have a status of PAUSED. I have a working code for it from the issue:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67846503/modifying-json-dictionaries-by-deleting-python). But I want to make it cleaner but attempting to configure the filters within the `filtered_data` dictionary but its not working. How would I be able to fix it?

Working:

```
def reading(): 
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    result = {}
    for filter_key in data.keys():
            for d in data[filter_key]:
                if d['Status'] == 'ACTIVE':
                    try:
                        result[filter_key].append(d)
                    except KeyError:
                        result[filter_key] = [d]
```

Not Working Code:

```
def reading(): 
    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    required_names = {key for filter_key in data.keys() for key in data[filter_key]}
    filtered_data = {
        key: value
        for key, value in data.keys()
        if key['Status'] in required_names 
    }
    return data
reading()
```

Expected Output:

```
{
    "RSI": [
      {
        "TradingPair": "BTCUSD",
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
      }
    ],
    "MOM_RSI":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BTCUSDT",
            "Status": "ACTIVE",
        }
    ]
}
```

JSON File:

```
{
    "RSI": [
      {
        "TradingPair": "BTCUSD",
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
      }
    ],
    "MOM":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BCHUSDT",
            "Status": "PAUSED",
        }
    ],
    "MOM_RSI":[
        {
            "TradingPair": "BTCUSDT",
            "Status": "ACTIVE",
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using inline loops to filter should do the trick for you

```
for key in data.keys():
    data[key] = [x for x in data[key] if x['Status'] == 'ACTIVE']

# in case of empty data, remove the key
data = {k: v for k, v in data.items() if v != []}
```